# Unable to add a Choice field to a Calculated field (SharePoint Foundation 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column, choice-field

I'm not sure why I'm having this issue, as all material says that I should be able to do this...

I have a required choice field that I would like to use in a calculated column. However, when I try to do so, I get the error:

> "One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas."

I'm not doing anything fancy, and have stripped down my formula in my calculated column to simply:

```
=[Event Type]
```

but still get the error. Am I missing something completely?

**Edit:** It looks like this is related to the list being migrated using DocAve Migration tools. Looking more into it through that venue.

Comment: Have you tried with the Internal nameof the field? http://sp2007hut.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/where-can-i-find-the-internal-fieldname-via-sharepoint-2010-gui/

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same problem. The actual issue is with the space inbetween Event and Type. So, I created a column 'EventType' and added the choice values. Created the calculated column which has reference to EventType. Now it will save without any issues.

After that edit the column and rename it to 'Event Type'. However you need not change the calculated field formula now as the SharePoint itself take care. If you go and view you can see the auto changed formula.

As you said this is a migration I am afraid you may get a data loss while you delete already existing field 'Event Type'

Answer (score 1):

What kind of choice column you have, if its multiple values then its not allowed.
[complete detail](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c4535103-d019-4e74-8529-39d8acf63a40/how-to-create-calculated-column-which-shows-yesno-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

But if its only one option then you can use it:
[=IF([Column A]=”Important”,[Column B]+[Column C],”Not Applicable”)](http://robhardyuk.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/today-i-had-a-s-9-2/)

Comment: I'm using a drop-down menu, so only once choice is allowed.

Comment: Is there any reason why just displaying the value wouldn't work (instead of using the IF statement)?

Comment: i just create a choice column with dropdown option( 3 choices), then in the Calculated column i just select the column from the list and its worked as expected. "columnname"

Comment: Hm. It's looking like this is a problem related the list being migrated from an older version of SharePoint. I can create a new choice column and add that without any issues - but the column that come over in the migration continues to give me issues.

Comment: what type of column in the old version?

Comment: It was a choice column as well - came from SharePoint 2007. Waiting to hear back from DocAve support if they're aware of any issues related to this.

Answer (score 1):

for me it works in choice column like :

```
=IF([column name]="choice value",TRUE,FALSE)
```

or try from list validation settings.

Answer (score 1):

This worked like a charm!

I had a choice field called "Current_supervisor".

I created another Calculated field "Current_Supervisor_Calc" having formula -

```
 =IF(ISERROR([Current_supervisor]),"-",[Current_supervisor])
```

then used this for actual/main Calculated field

```
 =IF(Current_Supervisor_Calc="-",[Supervisor_TEXT],[Current_supervisor])
```

Happy SharePointing!