# SharePoint List (Calculated Column adjusted to allow Multiple Selections)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I hope you can assist me with this issue i've got.

CONTEXT:

I have a SharePoint list containing a combination of dropdowns and calculated fields which has been working fine.

Column 1 (Dropdown): ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3" ]

Column 2 (Calculated): If('Column 1' = "Option 1", 5, IF('Column 1' = "Option 2", 4,...)

This worked for single selection dropdowns, but the powers that be, want it to be multiple selections now.

It's a simple fix on the dropdown column, but could I get some help on how to formulate Column 2 to have a specific number per option and then sum it all up at the end.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What is the logic for your Column 2 when dropdown is a multi-select? There is no straight forward answer to it. There is some workaround though. Visit [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86548/unable-to-add-a-choice-field-to-a-calculated-field-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, the **Calculated column** does not support **multiple Choice column** in SharePoint, it is by design.

[image]

[image]